# MySQL wrong query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need a query to the database which is checking the number in user_ref. If user_ref is 5 then denied.

Code:

```
if(!empty($_GET['ref'])){
    $resultt = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '{$_GET['ref']}' AND user_ref < 5 LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultt) > 0) {
```

Comment: Your question said that you only want to deny user_ref when it is equal to 5. Why in your query, you use the `user_ref < 5`? Isn't it supposed to be `user_ref = 5`

Comment: Hi Kim Bum. ;-) . Do you actually get mysql error 1064? MySQL does not "deny" as such, but it can return zero rows, as it will do with your current query if user_ref = 5 (because your query will only find results if user_ref is BELOW 5.

Answer (score 1):

use `<>`

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '{$_GET['ref']}' AND user_ref <> 5 LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: If user_ref is 5 then denied, it should be user_ref = 5 as indicated by invisal.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements `mysql_query()` is deprecated. For example PDO:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$user_ref = $_GET['ref'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_ref AND user_ref < 5 LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindValue(':user_ref', $user_ref, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$row_count = $stmt->rowCount(); // Returned rows..

foreach($rows as $row) {
   // I think this doesn't need any explanation
}
?>
```

Comment: When i got:
http://pastebin.com/nJ1CKL0L

I've got an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: Bud don't copy the old sql, fix it, replace the '{$_GET['ref']}' with the correct column name `user_ref`

Comment: '{$_GET['ref']}'  is a variable from the url

Comment: I know man, but ... The correct sql: `SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = :user_ref AND user_ref < 5 LIMIT 1` and you pass the value to the :user_ref (notice here the colon ) you passing the value in row:  `$sth->execute(array(':user_ref' => $_GET['ref']));`

Comment: Can You give me the whole code to replace this one: http://pastebin.com/nJ1CKL0L

Cause i'm getting errors for example:

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: @DawidWalczyk (Kim Bum), you need to take what people on StackOverflow say, and then adapt it to your own circumstances, you should not and generally can not get us / others to give you your work for you, you need to adapt and also (hopefully) learn from that.